# Reducing QListView to the common elements in the list?

Tags: c++, qt, qlistview

Is there a methode or simple approach to do this?

Given a list with:

```
D A B A B C D D
```

I want the list to be reduced to:

```
A B C D
```

Otherwise I will just write something to process in the background.

Comment: By "list", do you mean `QList`?

Comment: The elements are in QListView, but I guess they could be put in QList if there is a way to find the common elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how is your data storen and passed to the view. Generally, the simpliest way to remove duplicates from a list of element is converting it to set:

```
QStringList values;
//...
QSet<QString> set = values.toSet();
```

After that you can convert the set back to list using `toList` or iterate over a set using usual `foreach` loop. Note that `QSet` is unordered. If you want to sort your strings, convert the set to list and sort the list using `qSort`.